# 1000 GPIO Pins Microcontroller

Tags: gpio

I am working on a project and I'll be requiring over 1000 GPIO pins. Is it possible to get a extension of pins on Raspberry pi?

My project is pretty complex but here's the basic idea -

> I'll be having a 40 x 25 array of motors. I need to control each motor independently. To control each motor, I need many GPIO pins.

I'm not restricting my choice to Raspberry Pi and any hardware can work for me.

Comment: I'm actually curious if this is even remotely practical or possible.

Comment: Why not? I can make this possible using multiple mircontrollers. I just wanted to look for a more cost efficient way.

Comment: It might be better if you explained a little about your project as there may be a better way.

Comment: @CarlosSlim Look into the Compute Module and the Compute Module IO Board

Comment: @SteveRobillard I have modified the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @PatrickCook thanks a lot for the Compute Module. 128 pins per board are good enough because I can combine boards together.

Comment: Wouldn't a decentralized solution be easier/more robust? With 1000 inputs you have a central point of failure for the entire system. The other thing that leaps to mind is while you may be able to connect that many physical pins will the Pi have sufficient processing/memory power to keep pace with that type of load. Is this an art project or an industrial control application?

Comment: The project uses grids for power distribution. It can be compared to the Cartesian plane. Is it possible to use this fact?

Comment: Just came across this on adafruit's blog https://blog.adafruit.com/2016/04/04/how-to-add-128-extra-io-ports-without-upgrading-your-microcomputer/

Comment: Might also be worth a look at the implementation details of the glorious MIT inform table: http://goo.gl/ohY9y7 . They've made their own custom boards, but there might be some useful clues in there.

Comment: If the Compute Module is based on the Raspberry Pi it will have 54 GPIO (some of which will be reserved for system use).

Comment: Do you need to control speed and direction?  A fixed speed and direction needs 1 GPIO.  A variable speed needs a different solution.

Comment: fixed speed is required

Comment: I need 1000 output pins too, have you tried with shift registers?

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit have this comment on their [16 channel PWM/servo shield](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1411):

Using only two I2C pins, control 16 free-running PWM outputs! You can even stack up 62 shields to control up to 992 PWM outputs (which we would really like to see since it would be glorious and like 4 feet tall)

Although buying 62 shields would run you $1085 dollars. Not exactly a cheap option, but apparently workable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use up to 8 MCP23017 to give 128 pins. I have never actually done this, as I find it hard to conceive a project that would require so many - and which couldn't be managed in a better way

Comment: ...and 8 MCP23S17 on SPI (it may actually be 8 per SPI channel and if you do your own slave select that would be over 2500 GPIO).